# How do you use the team logo taunt?

Tags: league-of-legends

Recently I've seen a couple players use a team's logo as a taunt, as shown in the red square below.

[image]

My question is, "What's the keyboard shortcut for this taunt?"

Comment: This is almost certainly something that you can't do in-game normally. Worlds and other Riot-hosted professional events are played in a customized version of the game that includes team logos on the base walls and other stuff that's unavailable in the normal game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that's a champion master emote. So you'll need 4-5 of mastery on a champion.

> 2015 World Championship Team Icons [September 28 - November 5]:  Grab
>   a Worlds team icon for 250 RP and support your favorite team. If you
>   have a World Championship Team icon equipped during Worlds month, you
>   can display a special in-game emote of your team’s logo by activating
>   the mastery emote binding. After Patch 5.21, the emotes will retire as
>   we clean up the confetti, but the icons will stick around

Afterwards, just go into your settings, where you change your taunt and all that, put champion mastery on a key and you're set.

Comment: Just to add, the default keybinding for champion mastery emote is Ctrl + 6.